# Why example.com redirects and www.example.com not?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, bind

I have a working domain `www.mydomain.es` and I need that `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` redirects to it. This is my bind config:

```
$ttl 38400
mydomain.com.   IN  SOA r12345.ovh.net. admin.mydomain.es. (
            1338024563
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
mydomain.com.   IN  NS  r12345.ovh.net.
www.mydomain.com.   IN  NS  r12345.ovh.net.
```

and this is my apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/www/mydomain/site"
ServerName mydomain.com
<Directory "/home/user/www/mydomain/site">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.mydomain.es/
```

but it doesn't work... This redirects `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.es` but fails redirecting `www.mydomain.com` (not found). In fact, `mydomain.com` responds to ping, but `www.mydomain.com` not.

What's the problem?

Comment: Is this a complete Apache config, or a piece of a VirtualHost?

Comment: @Aredridel no, that's just the "interesting" part. Usually I use webmin, and this is the piece of the file I've added through webmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need DNS `A` or `CNAME` records in order for the names to resolve.

You current have `NS` entries pointing to `r12345.ovh.net.`, but that's for delegation, not generally single records - does that server have configuration to return a `A` or `CNAME` response?  Or did you mean to just CNAME those names to `r12345.ovh.net.` instead?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen the NS.. changed to A and it works perfectly :)